# mat-tab to show message while data source is loading and on empty result

Tags: angular, angular-material2

version: Angular 4.4, Material beta-12

I am wondering is there a way to show custom message when there is empty results or results loading for [mat-table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

i have gone through many materials and github issues and searching for any other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<mat-table> ... </mat-table>
<div *ngIf="noResults$ | async">No results</div>
```

It will display the header row, but no data rows. Instead it will show the "No results" message.

Getting `noResults$` set up will be very dependent on how your table retrieves data from the service, but maybe something like this will inspire a solution,

```
data$ = this.myService.getRowsOfData();

noResults$ = this.data$.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);
```

---

EDIT:

You can store the state inside the DataSource if you wish.

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource.empty">No results</div>
```

With a datasource that looks like this

```
empty = false;

connect(): Observable<MyData[]> {
  return Observable
    .of(whatever)
    .do(data => this.empty = !data.length);
}
```

Comment: is there any way to use datasource in ngIf?

Answer (score 1):

```
*ngIf="!dataSource.data.length"
```

Works on my machine... A6 however.

Comment: You may want to add a little more detail to your answer.

Comment: What is unclear about my one line of code? What part of it should be more detailed? It do not think it needs more details. It is an alternative solution to the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

*app.component.ts*

```
listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;
//assume no. of column = 6
```

*app.component.html*

```
//after ng-containers with mat-header-cell & mat-cell
<ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
   <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
      Loading data...
   </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
   <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
      No data.
   </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':listData!=null}">
   </mat-footer-row>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']" [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}">
   </mat-footer-row>
```

*style.css*

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```